# Ambiguous inheritance in policy-based design

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, ambiguity, policy-based-design

I have a host class, which takes two policies, `sayhello` and `talk`. The policy `talk` is a class template, which itself takes e.g. `sayhello`.
The problem is that `sayhello::saySomething` is ambiguous in `host2` (i tried to solve this diamond problem with `virtual`).

How can i resolve this ambiguity? Or is there in general a better design for such problems?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class sayhello {
protected:
    void saySomething(void) {
        std::cout<<"Hello!"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class talk : private T {
protected:
    void doSomething(void) {
        T::saySomething();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class host1 : virtual T {
public:
    void hostAction(void) {
        T::doSomething();
    }
};

template<typename T, typename L>
class host2 : private T, private L {
public:
    void hostAction(void) {
        T::doSomething();
        L::saySomething();
    }
};

int main() {
    host1<talk<sayhello> > HOST1;
    HOST1.hostAction(); // ok that works

    host2<talk<sayhello>,sayhello> HOST2;
    HOST2.hostAction(); // error, ambiguity!

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably abusing inheritance, but just add a couple more `virtual` keywords in both `talk` and `host2`:

```
#include <iostream>

class sayhello {
protected:
    void saySomething(void) {
        std::cout<<"Hello!"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class talk : virtual T {
protected:
    void doSomething(void) {
        T::saySomething();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class host1 : virtual T {
public:
    void hostAction(void) {
        T::doSomething();
    }
};

template<typename T, typename L>
class host2 : virtual T, virtual L {
public:
    void hostAction(void) {
        T::doSomething();
        L::saySomething();
    }
};

int main() {
    host1<talk<sayhello> > HOST1;
    HOST1.hostAction(); // ok that works

    host2<talk<sayhello>,sayhello> HOST2;
    HOST2.hostAction(); // error, ambiguity!

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/882c2fc3ae956237)

Comment: Thanks, TemplateRex, that exactly solved the problem. Could you please explain why you have the feeling that inheritance is abused here?

Comment: @the_ducky because a good policy-based design has *orthogonal* policies, with no possibilities of multiply inheriting the same class through different policies. One way to avoid that is as @DanielFrey showed, using a dummy class. But in your case, you might think about whether `sayHello::saySomething` and `talk::doSomething` could be a `static` member functions, so that you don't have to inherit from `T` ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3921d80aba9b14a))

Answer (score 1):

You could add a dummy class:

```
template<typename T> struct dummy : T {};

template<typename T, typename L>
class host2 : private T, private dummy<L> {
public:
    void hostAction(void) {
        T::doSomething();
        dummy<L>::saySomething();
    }
};
```

In some cases you will probably need to cast to `L` directly, which should work like this:

```
L& getL()
{
    return static_cast<L&>(static_cast<dummy<L>&>(*this));
}
```